# Young adult fantasy with a dying forest and a beaver like creature

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, audio-book

I encountered this as a book on tape in 2009, probably.  The narrator sounded like Brendan Fraser, but wasn’t. What made it memorable was the narration, as well as the detailed story line that wove threads of a hero with a side line of an ancient forest being poisoned by the pollution of evil magic. The trees in the forest would moan about dying (in English).  When all is put to right, the forest recovers.

The beaver like creature refers to the male human hero as “man monster”.

Comment: This is extremely brief is there anything else you can remember that you could [edit] in?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: 2009 is too early for Naomi Novik's _[Uprooted](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22544764-uprooted)_.